# Object not appearing the render, but is appearing in viewport render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate, but I have read anything I can find with "Object missing in render".

I am doing the updated blender 2.8 doughnut tutorial.

My Icing for my Doughnut is missing in action.

My icing appears just fine in the viewport, including in render mode. 
[image: doughnut]

However if I do an actual render:
[image: dougnut render]

It does not seem to be disabled, these are the setting I have already checked and they all seem to make sence.

[image: settings 1]
[image: settings 2]

Comment: Did you use Texture paint for the icing?

Comment: Not I sculpted it, and created materials, but not done a texture paint yet.

Comment: I have painted vertex weights over it for the sprinkle/particle density but thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However I have not watched this tutorial but it seems particle system is used for sprinkles on ice and I think You Have Disabled the 'Show Emmiter' Option in Particle settings
but in viewport display it is enabled that's why this ice is shown in viewport but not in rendered view

for emmiter ie; ice to be visible in rendered view just go to particle settings and in render check "show emmiter " and this will work

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This was the fix ! Thank you